# how to compare the file names using wild card characters in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an output from Get Metadata stage as below

"exists": "true",
"childitems":[
"name":"20221232_qbx_abc.txt",
"type":"File"
{
"name":"2022_data_new_q32.txt",
"type":"File"
}

I want to compare the file name using wild cards like
if my file name contains string "qbx_abc" and "data_new I need to proceed for next stage

how to achieve this on if condition stage

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample pipeline code using the contains function, which can check strings for contained values:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "x",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@contains(pipeline().parameters.test, 'abc')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "test": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "123_abc_xyz.csv"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "x": {
                "type": "Boolean"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: contains expression can help. above is the pipeline json

Comment: Format the pipeline json as code and add some explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop the Get Metadata **child items** using ForEach activity.

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

2. Inside the `ForEach` activity, add the `If condition` activity to validate the filename if it contains the required string.

- Use or() to check if the file name contains any one of your string values.
- Use and() to validate if the file name contains both the string values in it.

Ex: `@or(contains(item().name, 'qbx_abc'), contains(item().name, 'data_new'))`

[image]

3. In True activities, add other activities to process the next steps.